# how to use an if statement to go back to previous code in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

So I'm trying to make a text adventure game in Python 2.7 with limited options. I want to find a way where if an answer that isn't programmed in is input, it will re-ask the question. Thanks.

```
while True:  
print "You wake up in a dim room. Cold water trickles down your spine through the rags you are wearing." 
  break
while True:
  q1 = raw_input("Exit or Explore? ")
  if q1 in ("explore", "Explore","EXPLORE",):
    print "You search the room. All you find is a small, maroon object. You reach for it, but all of the sudden, it explodes. You are dead."
    exit()
  elif q1 in ("exit","EXIT","Exit",):
    print "Light flashes before your eyes as you find yourself on a scenic mountaintop. It drops to the north and west. To the east is a winding road. In the distance you see a village."
  else:
    print "..."
  q2 = raw_input("Which direction do you go? ")
  if q2 in ("North","north","NORTH","West","west","WEST",):
    print "You clumsily stumble off the cliff. You are dead."
    exit()
  elif q2 in ("east","EAST","East",):
    print "You travel for a few hours and arrive at"
    break
```

Comment: Just a side note, but the first while loop you have isn’t necessary. You can just print out that text.

Answer (score 2):

There is a feature implemented in most programming languages called a `method` or `function`.
 Basically what a function does is when you call it, you also call any instructions you defined in that function. Oh yeah and just for the record `method` and `function` are practically the same.
So in your case you could have something like:

```
def exit_or_explore():
    q1 = raw_input("Exit or Explore? ")

    if q1 in ("explore", "Explore","EXPLORE",):
        print "You search the room. All you find is a small, maroon object. You reach for it, but all of the sudden, it explodes. You are dead."
        exit()
    elif q1 in ("exit","EXIT","Exit",):
        print "Light flashes before your eyes as you find yourself on a scenic mountaintop. It drops to the north and west. To the east is a winding road. In the distance you see a village."
    else:
        exit_or_explore()
exit_or_explore()
```

You define the function with keyword `def` and whenever you want to call anything in the code you call it like `function()`
What happens is if the user doesn't respond with any of your words listed it calls the function `exit_or_exlore()` which repeats the code inside it.

Next time please format your code properly

Comment: If this post helped you please consider marking it as an anwser.